# Ok(keys) returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am writing logic to fetch certs from keycloak api and when I compile the program I am getting below error.

`Ok(keys) returns a value referencing data owned by the current function`

```rs
async fn get_jwt_keys() -> Result<&'static KeycloakCertRespKeys, Error> {
    let request_url = format!("http://x.x.x.x:5000/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/certs");
    println!("{}", request_url);
    let response = reqwest::get(&request_url).await?;
    // println!("{:?}", response);
    let certs: KeycloakCertResp = response.json().await?;
    let keys: &KeycloakCertRespKeys = certs.keys.first().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", keys.kid);
    Ok(keys)
}
```

Comment: I can probably infer what question you're trying to ask, but as it currently stands this post is just a comment/statement of fact and isn't asking anything at all.

Comment: In particular, the returned value is owned by `certs`, which exists in `get_jwt_keys`'s stack frame and therefore goes out of scope/ceases to exist when the function returns.  Therefore, if Rust were to allow this, the returned reference would be pointing into no-longer allocated memory, triggering Undefined Behaviour.  The fact that you've had to specify the `'static` lifetime in the function signature is indicative of this problem: because the function doesn't take any arguments, any reference it returns must necessarily be into memory that is *always* available—but `certs` is not.

Comment: As regards what is the solution here... it really depends on what you're trying to do.  To literally fix this function using its present signature, you *could* consider storing `certs` in a static (e.g. behind a [`LocalKey`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html) or a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html)).  Alternatively, you might consider returning `certs` from the function and having the caller invoke `.keys.first().unwrap()` as required; or wrapping `certs` in some struct that provides the result of those calls behind a `fn first_key(&self)`?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right. If you look when the variable **keys** is created, its type is a reference. The function returns Ok(that reference).

The reference indeed references data available only to that function, that gets dealocated when that variable gets out of scope.

To solve the problem, you may call **to_owned** method and return the actual object instead of a reference, or **clone** if the type you have, **KeycloakCertRespKeys**, does not implement **ToOwned** trait. Note that the return type might change (remove **&'static**).

As mentioned in one of the previous comments, the compiler forces you to specify a static lifetime to make sure that the data is available throughout the whole time while the program executes.